# screenshot canvas getUserMedia Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I want to make a screnshot of the wecam video in Chrome beta. 
The code only produces a screenshot of a small part of the video, what went wrong?

here the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9XKh/

Answer (score 8):

You haven't specified the dimensions of your `canvas` element so it is being created at the default size (300x150) which is smaller than the dimensions of the `video` element. As a result, when you draw the `video` to the `canvas` the snapshot is being cropped.

I would update the `snapshot` method to set the `canvas` width and height to match those of the `video` element like so:

```
  // create snapschot          
  function snapshot() {

         // set the canvas to the dimensions of the video
         canvas.width = video.clientWidth;
         canvas.height = video.clientHeight;

         ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

         document.getElementById("huhu").src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');

  }
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EUkDS/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was stuck ! Example from htmlrocks is not mentionning it.